# Atributo condicional en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, condiciones

Tengo un componente `TextField` de MUI con react y quiero que se coloque o elimine el atributo `error` dependiendo de la constante `verify`, ya que si solo cambio el valor siempre me lo toma como verdadero aunque sea un string vacío `error=""`.

```
  <TextField error={`${verify ? false : true}`} label="Usuario" variant="filled" color="secondary" onChange={event => setPsw(event.target.value)}/>
```

Las formas en puedo evitar que `error` sea `false` es:

```
error = {false}
error = {null}
//error <- eliminar el atributo
```

Si es con comillas de algun tipo lo toma como verdarero.

Comment: Quizas esta pregunta te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163693/how-do-i-conditionally-add-attributes-to-react-components

Comment: Entonces este componente va a ser renderizado de una? o ese verify se va a modificar y quieres que el error aparezca o desaparezca? porque si es el caso, deberías usar una variable en el state, pues son las que hacen que el componente se renderice

Answer (score 0):

La solución que aplique la obtuve de esta otra pregunta similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163693/how-do-i-conditionally-add-attributes-to-react-components:

```
{...(verify ? {} : {error: 'success'})}
```